# Calendar under Web Part in Sharepoint

Tags: web-part, calendar

is it possible to show 3-month period of a calendar under a web part in sharepoint? Basically, it only shows per month period (which is the current month). Is there any way to customize it? In this way, it would be easier to monitor and track events for a given period. Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to modify the ootb calendar do show a 3 month basis. What you maybe could do would be to have 3 calendars and somehow if you could set them to show 3 different months and make them small using CSS and the script editor/content editor web part. http://sp2013.blogspot.se/2014/05/sharepoint-calendar-dont-show-current.html http://erikswenson.blogspot.se/2013/04/small-calendar-for-sharepoint-2010-2013.html